# Having Docker image renaming issue

Tags: docker

When I am renaming my docker repository it is just creating another image with a different repository name, else everything is same. What does this means?

Comment: Please add the commands that you are using, or define more in detail what steps you take with examples.

Comment: i think you mean tag, a image may have many tags. if you want to retag it, just add a tag, and delete old tag

Answer (score 0):

It's the right approach

For renaming a docker image you first tag the current image and docker will automatically make a copy of the current image, Then you should delete the old image

Take a look at below example

```
docker image tag <old-image-id> <new-image-name>
```

OR

```
docker image tag <old-image-name:old-image-tag> <new-image-name:new-image-tag>
```

Then check your existing images yous should see the old image and new renamed one

After that, You can delete the old one,